# Generating function of non-linear recursion

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

[image]

[image]

I'm just not able to understand how they got from where they substituted a subscript n after the second equals to sign from 5.27  to  x(A(x))^2

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If $f(x)=\sum a_nx^n$ and $g(x)=\sum b_nx^n$ then $f(x)g(x)=\sum c_nx^n$ where $c_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kb_{n-k}$. See how the sum inside the parentheses is like this sum for $c_n$.

Comment: The transformation that takes two sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ and produces $(c_n)$ with $c_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kb_{n-k}$ is called convolution $(a_n)\star(b_n)$. The transform that takes sequences to generating functions ($(a_n)\mapsto \sum a_nx^n$) turns convolution into multiplication of series.

Comment: Minor correction: we have $c_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}$.